# Not able to populate the picklist (dropdown) with Resource Group Name for Custom Task Azure DevOps Extension

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-devops-extensions

Below is the **task.json** file. That fetches the ResourceGroupName for the picklist dynamically when the user selects the Service Connection within ConnectedServiceName. But when I run the script, I get a blank dropdown as per the screenshot below.

```
 "inputs": [ 
    {
        "name": "ConnectedServiceName",
        "type": "connectedService:AzureRM",
        "label": "AzureRM Subscription",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "Select the Azure Resource Manager subscription for the deployment."
    },
    {
        "name": "dynamicPicklistInput",
        "type": "pickList",
        "label": "Dynamic Picklist Input",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "required": true,
        "properties": {
            "EditableOptions": "True"
        },
        "helpMarkDown": "Enter or Select an existing Slot other than the Production slot."
    }
 ],
 "dataSourceBindings": [
    {
        "target": "dynamicPicklistInput",
        "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
        "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/subscriptions/$(endpoint.subscriptionId)/resourcegroups?api-version=2021-04-01",
        "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*].name",
        "resultTemplate":  "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{name}}}\", \"DisplayValue\":\"{{{name}}}\"}"
    }
],
```

[image: Screenshot Image]

Require your help to provide me either a useful complete sample that includes vss-extension.json or help me understand where I am doing wrong.